# Getting "Animal" class into "Dog" class - values

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an `Animal` base class and a `Dog` that inherits from.

```
class Dog: Animal
```

I have a service which returns an Animal, I don't control it.

Is there a way to get a `Dog` object from the `Animal`, but with the Animal's values without manually copying the animal values to Dog ?

Comment: Can you modify animal to implement IClonable?

Comment: The accepted answer says you can't, but can't you just cast? (i.e. Dog dog = (Dog)animalVariable;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to write code which will describe how `Dog` can be created from `Animal`.

You can do this as additional constructor:

```
public Dog(Animal source)
{
    // copy value
    // (...) 
}
```

With that you can just say:

```
var dog = new Dog(myAnimalReceivedFromService);
```